# SubGrid doesn't receive focus on IE only, running CRM 2011 UR16

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

**TL;DR** SubGrids don't focus on click in IE10/11, but work in Chrome. This happens in UR16, doesn't happen in UR15. IE's Compatibility View doesn't change the behavior. No errors whatsoever are reported by console or CRM itself.

---

I'm having issues with SubGrids in a form, in IE only:

- Clicking in the white space inside the subgrids doesn't cause them to get focus
- Subsequently, the ribbon doesn't change to show the contextual commands for the related entity
- Clicking the SubGrid headers seems to function properly (the SubGrid reloads and I can see the tiny arrow showing the sort order has changed)

This happens both in IE10 and IE11, both with and without adding the website to Compatibility View.

Neither the CRM itself nor the debugger show any script errors, and opening the exact same record in Chrome doesn't show any oddity and everything works perfectly.

Lastly, the CRM with the issue has UR16, but the same issue does NOT occur on a replica environment (with the exact same customizations) which still has UR15.

This seems like a UR16 issue, the complete lack of any error indication isn't making it easy to isolate the specific cause though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late but i will post for the upcoming reads on these.

In Explorer 10 and 11, when a user does not have write rights in form entity, the whole form is disabled preventing to have focus event when clicking in the subgrids. (it works in chrome)
You can enable the subgrids using a Javascript, but be sure to enable only for the users with rights in the subgrid entity.

```js
document.getElementById(subgridName + "_span").removeAttribute("disabled");
```

best